# List of positive elements

Tags: prolog

Write a predicate in Prolog that calculates the list of positive elements of a list.

```
pos( [] , [] ) .  
pos( [H|T] , L ) :-   L is N > 0, pos(T,N)
```

right?

Comment: `right?` Try some examples. e.g `pos([1,-1,1,-1],R)` and see what happens.

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to install Prolog, you can use https://swish.swi-prolog.org.

Comment: I see this is now your second question where if is clear that you have not tried your solution proposal yourself. As you are asking for some effort by the community, I suggest that you put in a little more effort yourself, please.

Answer (score 0):

What is `N`? And what do you do with `H`? Inquiring minds want to know.

Try something like this:

```
pos( []     , []     ) .
pos( [N|Ns] , [N|Rs] ) :- N >  0 , pos(Ns,Rs).
pos( [_|Ns] ,    Rs  ) :- N =< 0 , pos(Ns,Rs).
```